# Access Model Training History in TFLearn?

Tags: tflearn

I want to save train and validation loss in csv files in tflearn, and then reload it like we do in keras with history to plot graphs. Please help me

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this will help but you can save the model with this code: `model.save('mnist.tflearn')` After that whenever you want, you can to reload the model back. Below is an example to reload the model:

```
from __future__ import division, print_function, absolute_import
import tflearn.datasets.mnist as mnist
import csv
import tflearn
from tflearn.layers.core import input_data,dropout, fully_connected
from tflearn.layers.conv import conv_2d, max_pool_2d
from tflearn.layers.estimator import regression
from tflearn.data_preprocessing import ImagePreprocessing
from tflearn.data_augmentation import ImageAugmentation
from tflearn.metrics import Accuracy


X, Y, test_x, test_y = mnist.load_data(one_hot=True)

shape = 28
X = X.reshape([-1, shape, shape, 1])
test_x = test_x.reshape([-1, shape, shape, 1])

###################################
# Image transformations
###################################

# normalisation of images
img_prep = ImagePreprocessing()
img_prep.add_featurewise_zero_center()
img_prep.add_featurewise_stdnorm()

# Create extra synthetic training data by flipping & rotating images
img_aug = ImageAugmentation()
img_aug.add_random_flip_leftright()
img_aug.add_random_rotation(max_angle=25.)

###################################
# Define network architecture
###################################

# Input is a 32x32 image with 3 color channels (red, green and blue)
network = input_data(shape=[None, shape, shape, 1],
                     data_preprocessing=img_prep,
                     data_augmentation=img_aug)


# 1: Convolution layer with 32 filters, each 3x3x3
conv_1 = conv_2d(network, 32, 2, activation='relu', name='conv_1')

# 2: Max pooling layer
network = max_pool_2d(conv_1, 2)
# 12: Dropout layer to combat overfitting
network = dropout(network, 0.8)

# 3: Convolution layer with 64 filters
conv_2 = conv_2d(network, 64, 2, activation='relu', name='conv_2')

# 2: Max pooling layer
network = max_pool_2d(conv_2, 2)
# 12: Dropout layer to combat overfitting
network = dropout(network, 0.8)

# 4: Convolution layer with 64 filters
conv_3 = conv_2d(network, 64, 2, activation='relu', name='conv_3')

# 5: Max pooling layer
network = max_pool_2d(conv_3, 2)
# 12: Dropout layer to combat overfitting
network = dropout(network, 0.8)

# 5: Convolution layer with 64 filters
conv_4 = conv_2d(network, 128, 2, activation='relu', name='conv_4')

# 6: Max pooling layer
network = max_pool_2d(conv_4, 2)
# 12: Dropout layer to combat overfitting
network = dropout(network, 0.8)

# 7: Convolution layer with 64 filters
conv_5 = conv_2d(network, 256, 2, activation='relu', name='conv_5')

# 8: Max pooling layer
network = max_pool_2d(conv_5, 2)
# 12: Dropout layer to combat overfitting
network = dropout(network, 0.8)

# 9: Convolution layer with 64 filters
conv_6 = conv_2d(network, 256, 2, activation='relu', name='conv_6')

# 10: Max pooling layer
network = max_pool_2d(conv_6, 2)

# 12: Dropout layer to combat overfitting
network = dropout(network, 0.8)

# 11: Fully-connected 512 node layer
network = fully_connected(network, 1024, activation='relu')


# 13: Fully-connected layer with two outputs
network = fully_connected(network, 10, activation='softmax')

# Configure how the network will be trained
acc = Accuracy(name="Accuracy")
network = regression(network, optimizer='adam',
                     loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                     learning_rate=0.0005, metric=acc)

# Wrap the network in a model object
model = tflearn.DNN(network)
model.load('mnist.tflearn')
for i in xrange(0, len(testX)):
    im = [testX[i]]
    a = model.predict(im)
```